# Access a NodeJS variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

For security purposes, is there a way to access and print in the console (or to sniff) a variable in server- and/or client-side JavaScript?

Would you consider safe to store in a variable the passphrase to encrypt account sensitive data (and then obfuscate the .js file)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Of course you can access variables. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: *"Would you consider safe to store in a variable the passphrase to encrypt account sensitive data (and then obfuscate the .js file)?"* Only if it's a public key in a public/private pair. (And no obfuscation required if so.)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. On the client your can do whatever you want. Client can't access server variables directly. Passphrase? Anything in the client side is accessible.

Comment: @DaveNewton He literally ended the post with a one sentence question. And your answer to that question is a no. Seems like a pretty clear question to me.

Comment: He... literally (?) started the post with a different question, too ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Perhaps I'm just dense, but I found little clear here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you do not want to store keys on the client side, since it will be consumed by the public. Some services do provide client keys, which are fine, since they are client specific.

On the server-side, keys can be used freely. However, they should not be hardcoded into your source code. Instead, inject them into the Node environment, and use them like so `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean logging a variable? You can just 
    `console.log(variable`)
in line in your code. and it will show up in the terminal of whatever server you're running. For a deployed server, it would really depend on where you're hosting, but the console.log will show up in the logs, on heroku for example you could do something like

heroku logs

But otherwise you shouldn't be able to externally access variables during runtime, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You should never store a variable in js file. Instead of storing it in a js file, you can enter passphrase when you start your application as a command line argument. In this way, only the one who have started application will know about the value of passphrase. and nobody can sniff it or access. You can pass command line argument as

```
node app.js <passphrase>
```

and you can access this passphrase in you application anywhere with

```
console.log(process.argv)
```